# Android: SQLite: If isDatabaseIntegrityOK() returns false

Tags: java, android, sqlite, logging, data-integrity

if SQLiteDatabase.isDatabaseIntegrityOK() returns false, how do i get access to the 1-100 lines of logs the database is supposed to return?

I want to display the results of the integrity check in my Android app.

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean "the 1-100 lines of logs the database is supposed to return" ?

Comment: SQLite's [PRAGMA integrity_check](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_integrity_check) command returns strings which describe the problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just execute the command yourself, and pretend that it's a `SELECT`:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA integrity_check", null);
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    String s = cursor.getString(0);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternative using Android's DatabaseUtils:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(db.rawQuery("PRAGMA integrity_check", null), sb);
```